# Is Jesus in Matthew 23:37 quoting 2 Esdras 1:30?

Tags: hebrew, matthew, latin, 2esdras

> O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, thou that killest the prophets, and stonest
> them which are sent unto thee, how often would ***I have gathered thy
> children together, even as a hen gathereth her chickens under her
> wings***, and ye would not! **(Matthew 23:37, KJV)**

> ***I gathered you as a hen gathers her chicks under her wings***. But now,
> what shall I do to you? I will cast you out from my presence. **(2
> Esdras 1:30, NRSV)**

Latin Vulgate manuscrpit; **ita vos collegi ut gallina filios suos sub alas suas.** modo autem quid faciam vobis? proiciam vos a facie mea.

---

Most scholars agree that 4th Ezra was original composed in Hebrew. The Hebrew version, which is now lost was later translated into Greek. The Greek version, which of has survived only in bits of fragments paraphrases and quotations and by later authors was translated into Latin which has addition of an introduction (chapters 1-2), Syriac manuscript (7a1), Ethiopic, Georgian, Arabic, Armenian and Coptic start from chapter 3.

Evidence of the Greek fragments. Definite quotations or paraphrases of the Greek text of 4 Ezra include the following:

4 Ezra 5:35 - Clement of Alexandria, Stromateis 3:16
4 Ezra 7:103 - Apostolic Constitutions 2.14.9
4 Ezra 8:23 - Apostolic Constitutions 8.7.6

Possible quotations, allusions to 4 Ezra:

4 Ezra 5:5a - Barnabas 12:1
4 Ezra 7:94 - Vision of Hermas 1.3 (allusion)
4 Ezra 14:21-22, 37-47  - Clement of Alexandria, Stromateis 1:22 (allusion)

[Source:](https://pseudepigrapha.org/docs/intro/4Ezra)

- Is 2 Esdras 1:30 a prophecy that Jesus later quotes?
- Is 2 Esdras original Hebrew written before the book of Matthew?
- Is 2 Esdras 1 & 2 from Latin Vulgate added or Syriac, Ethiopic, Georgian, Arabic, Armenian and Coptic lost chapter 1, 2?

Comment: @NigelJ Thanks Nigel I know about them!

Comment: No, it is a much later Christian interpolation, added to an otherwise Jewish text. And the first two and last two chapters are independent books, called Fifth and Sixth Ezra, which were not originally part of Second Esdras, the latter consisting initially only of Fourth Ezra (chapters 3-14), written around AD 100, as can easily be glimpsed from its various passages.

Answer (score 5):

This link in Wikipedia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Esdras  says that tradition reckons this to have been written by 5th century BCE priest and scribe, Ezra, but scholarship places its composition between 70 and 218 CE.  If the scholars are correct, then whoever wrote 2 Esdras was repeating Jesus’ original words. The main body of the book appears to be written for consolation in a period of great distress. One scholarly hypothesis is that it dates to the destruction of Jerusalem and its second temple in 70 CE by Titus. That city and temple were still standing when Jesus uttered his prophetic words in Matthew 23:27.

That would mean that whoever wrote 2 Esdras was largely repeating the words of Jesus which he spoke nearly 40 years before they were fulfilled. And Matthew had written those words in his gospel account of Jesus before A.D. 70, and possibly even as early as A.D. 50. Only if 2 Esdras had been written before Jesus was born could this question raise the possibility of Jesus quoting from an older, prophetic source. He certainly quoted many times from the ancient Hebrew scriptures commonly known as the Old Testament, but in this case it is logical that Jesus could not have quoted from a book that had not yet been written.

Comment: Agreed - 2 Edsras quotes Jesus/Matthew not the other way around.  This is typical of a pseudepigraphon.  If God had intended that this work be pert of the Bible canon, the God would have preserved it in it original language rather than the appalling dilapidated state we now find it.

Comment: @Dottard: There is nothing appalling or dilapidated about its state; books before the Babylonian captivity were mostly in Hebrew (Masoretic and Samaritan); then, an Aramaic layer was understandably added (Chronicles, Ezra-Nehemiah, Esther, Daniel); then, a Greek one (the Apocrypha, the canonical Septuagint, and the New Testament), due to the rise of the Macedonian and Ptolemaic empires; then, a Latin one (Second Esdras), due to the political and military momentum gained by the Roman empire around the time of Trajan.

Comment: @Lucian - you have made the point well - non of the canonical books have these "layers" of various languages and re-translation and later additions.  All exist in the original language.  Edras is a mish-mash of who knows what.

Comment: @Dottard: The canonical scriptures have three layers: Hebrew (most OT), Aramaic (some OT), and Greek (NT).

Comment: @lucian masoretic is pre Babylonian captivity to you?  Could you explain please?

Comment: @Lucian  2 hours ago, Nihil Sine Deo left you this comment, but due to not capitalising the first letter of your name, you might not get it. Here's what he asked you: 
masoretic is pre Babylonian captivity to you? Could you explain please? –

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this answer is it ignores the very obvious quoting of 2nd Esdras in the Qumran scrolls demonstrating it was circulated and used in 100 B.C.. In the 100 B.C. fragment of 1QpHab, found in Cave 1 [Vermes, 510-11], Ezra's prophecy from 2nd Esdras 11-12 is firmly the origin of this local interpretation of scripture thus, the book was certainly around and used at that time written before Jesus came in the flesh. Then, The Blessing of the Prince of the Congregation (1QSb, 100 B.C. also) [Vermes, p. 389-390], is a very direct quotation of Ezra's Eagle Empire found in the same chapters of 2nd Esdras.

This scholar represents a very backwards false narrative that is not accurate at all. 2nd Esdras preceded Matthew by more than a century and thus, is the origin of Matthew 23:37 which is Yahusha very directly quoting 2 Esdras 1:30 period. This answer is false.

Additionally, 1st Esdras is indisputably found in proto fragments erroneously contributed to Esther is poor guessing by uneducated scholars. The so-called "Proto-Esther" fragments identify the Father (Patir, how is it supoosed Bible scholar do not know this) Ezra (Eza) who is a male and never Esther in some of the worst scholarship we have seen. The story is 1st Esdras on each fragment labeled erroneously as "ProtoEsther" with Ezra identified even and could never be attributed to the Book of Esther. It is not even her story which is not even found until Josephus, the admitted Pharisee first published that Pharisee-style propaganda in 90 A.D. That is why even the 1611 KJV anchors NO portions of Esther to the New Testament even Purim which festival was not kept by Bible believers. 1st Esdras in the ancient Canons included 2nd Esdras as one book as well at times and many scholars overlook that as well as Daniel and Jeremiah including some so-called "apocryphal" books which were not separated out in that era.

The Qumran community cited 2nd Esdras twice in their local writings in their interpretation of prophecy. The first is their Commentary on Habukkuk:

100 B.C.: 1QpHab, Cave 1 [Vermes, 510-11]: Their horses are swifter than leopards and fleeter than evening wolves. Their horses step forward proudly and spread their wings; they fly from afar like an eagle avid to devour. All of them come for violence; the look on their faces is like the east wind (i, 8~9a).

[Interpreted, this] concerns the Kittim who trample the earth with their horses and beasts. They come from afar, from the islands of the sea, to devour all the peoples like an eagle which cannot be satisfied, and they address [all the peoples] with anger and [wrath and fury] and indignation. For it is as He said, The look on their faces is like the east wind.

This is really drawing from 2nd Esdras:

2 Esdras 11:1-2 KJVA

```
Then I saw a dream, and behold, there came up from the Sea an Eagle, which had twelve feathered wings, and three heads. And I saw, and behold, she spread her wings over all the earth, and all the winds of the air blew on her, and were gathered together.
```

2 Esdras 12:3 KJVA

```
And I saw, and behold, they appeared no more, and the whole body of the Eagle was burnt, so that the earth was in great fear:
```

2 Esdras 12:24 KJVA

```
And of those that dwell therein with much oppression, above all those that were before them: therefore are they called the heads of the Eagle.
```

Then, even more compelling is their prophecy of John the Baptist blessing Messiah (Prince of the Congregation). This is one of those that will raise the hairs on the back of one's neck as it is full of language from 2nd Esdras not found anywhere else.

The Blessing of the Prince of the Congregation (1QSb, 100 B.C.) [56]

```
The Master (John the Baptist) shall bless the Prince of the Congregation (Yahusha) . . . and shall renew for him the Covenant of the Community that he may establish the kingdom of His people for ever, [that he may judge the poor with righteousness and] dispense justice with {equity to the oppressed} of the land, and that he may walk perfectly before Him in all the ways [of truth], and that he may establish His holy Covenant at the time of the affliction of those who seek God. May the Lord raise you up to everlasting heights, and as a fortified tower upon a high wall! [May you smite the peoples] with the might of your hand and ravage the earth with your sceptre; may you bring death to the ungodly with the breath of your lips! [May He shed upon you the spirit of counsel] and everlasting might, the spirit of knowledge and of the fear of God; may righteousness be the girdle [of your loins] and may your reins be girdled [with faithfulness]! May He make your horns of iron and your hooves of bronze; may you toss like a young bull [and trample the peoples] like the mire of the streets! For God has established you as the sceptre. The rulers ... [and all the kings of the] nations shall serve you. He shall strengthen you with His holy Name and you shall be as a [lion; and you shall not lie down until you have devoured the] prey which naught shall deliver – Calendars, Liturgies and Prayers, p. 389-390.
```

John the Baptist, the son of Zadok through his mother’s bloodline, and the priestly line of Abiyah through his father’s (Luke 1:5), lived and operated in Bethabara (see Introduction) as a leader or master. He baptized Messiah in the place where Yahusha launched His ministry in Bethabara, not in the Jerusalem Temple (Jn. 1:28-36). Only Messiah fits this Prince of the Congregation as he is the judge of all (2 Esd. 12:33, 8:18, 7:33, 7:44, 7:69, 8:18, 13:37, 11:46). He has a kingdom established forever (2 Esd. 9:1-8) and He established His covenant which fits no prophet (2 Esd. 13:38). Yahusha is the Scepter in prophecy (Gn. 49:10, Nm. 24:17, Hb. 1:18) who smites the ungodly peoples in the end (2 Esd. 9:9-13) and all kings will only serve Messiah and no one else (Psalm 72:11, Is. 45:22-25, Phil. 2:10, Rom. 14:11). Literally, He came in the name of Yahuah (Yahusha, Jn. 5:43) and no one can deliver those whom He judges and condemns to Hell (2 Esd. 7:45, 13:38). Only Yahusha brings death spiritually and in finality to the ungodly (2 Esd. 13:11, 49) and with His breath or as 2nd Esdras is being represented there, with fire from His mouth (2 Esd. 13:4, 10, 27, 38). Remember, Revelation is not written yet, this is quoting 2nd Esdras in large part with a clear understanding of prophecy in general. Even the Lion Messiah is mentioned prominently in 2nd Esdras (2 Esd. 11:37, 12:31-32).

This is overwhelmingly 2nd Esdras content as a whole being used by the Temple Priests to interpret prophecy. One of the most telling is the manner in which Yahusha consumes the wicked on the Day of Judgment which is very specific to 2nd Esdras though the whole passage coalesces with 2nd Esdras.

2 Esdras 13:9-11 KJVA

```
And lo, as he saw the violence of the multitude that came, he neither lift up his hand, nor held sword, nor any instrument of war. But only I saw that he sent out of his mouth, as it had been a blast of fire, and out of his lips a flaming breath, and out of his tongue he cast out sparks and tempests, And they were all mixed together; the blast of fire, the flaming breath, and the great tempest, and fell with violence upon the multitude, which was prepared to fight, and burnt them up every one, so that upon a sudden, of an innumerable multitude, nothing was to be perceived, but only dust and smell of smoke: when I saw this, I was afraid.
```

2 Esdras 13:38 KJVA

```
And shall lay before them their evil thoughts, and the torments wherewith they shall begin to be tormented, which are like unto a flame: and he shall destroy them without labor, by the law which is like unto fire.
```

2 Esdras 11:37 KJVA

```
And I beheld, and lo, as it were a roaring Lion, chased out of the wood: and I saw that he sent out a man’s voice unto the Eagle, and said, Hear you, I will talk with you, and the Highest shall say unto you, Are you not it that remains of the four beasts, whom I made to reign in my world, that the end of their times might come through them?
```

2 Esdras 11:31-32 KJVA

```
And behold, the head was turned with them that were with it, and did eat up the two feathers under the wing that would have reigned. But this head put the whole earth in fear, and bare rule in it over all those that dwelt upon the earth, with much oppression, and it had the governance of the world more then all the wings that had been.
```

We also publish 2nd Esdras: The Hidden Book of Prophecy free in eBook at 2Esdras.org.

Yah Bless.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: @TheGodCulture Thank you for the contribution. Could you add the commentary from Habakkuk on 2nd Esdras 11 Eagle and Lion Vision, I have a hard time find it interpret only the fragment I find.